# php sql error (from,order,where position)

Tags: php, sql

i made this:

```
$query1=mysql_query("select id, testo, titolo from events order by DESC WHERE id < 225 LIMIT 1");
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo $query2['titolo'];
}
```

But doesn't work, i don't understand why, someone can help me?
I think the problem is in the query.

UPDATE: I made two mistakes:

The first: i have missing the column name in order by clause.
The second: The position of ORDER

Comment: Do you look at the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html. `select ...from... where... order...limit`.

Comment: @chris85 cool explanation :)

Comment: @chris85: Thanks for your link. I have added it in my answer :)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your query as below:-

```
SELECT id, testo, titolo FROM events WHERE id < 225 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

As suggested by [*chris85*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85), For understanding select ...from... where... order...limit,

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is very useful.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: An explanation of WHY to the OP would be helpful.

Comment: @patricksweeney: I have added link for information. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ORDER BY` before `WHERE` Clause you can not get the result like this way.

Second issue is that you didn't mentioned the id column or any other column in `ORDER BY`.

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT id, testo, titolo FROM events WHERE id < 225 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

*Side note:*

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` becuase this extension deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

you have at least 2 errors. Rewrite your query to look like:

```
SELECT id, testo, titolo FROM events WHERE id < 225 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the column name in your order by clause. That section should be something like `order by col_name desc`. Also the where clause comes before the order by as described in above answers.